# TabBar screen disappears right after launching app in simulator

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard

When i launch my app in simulator. My test app consist of only Tab Bar Controller and two View Controllers. At the beginning I can see first screen, but in moments it disappears.[image]

Comment: The storyboard looks ok. Could you share a demo project that shows the same problem?

Comment: dasdom it is demo project, I learn Tab bar functionality and encountered on this issue

Comment: I didn't touch any generated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my bad. I placed these view controllers on LaunchScreen.storyboard. When I removed all this stuff to the Main.storyboard all worked fine.